# Case query sql command in asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have written a query in sqlserver which is working perfectly. Now I want to add this query on a button click in asp.net to fill grid. How to write this?

This is my query:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
var command= "SELECT ActName,
    CASE WHEN SUM(DebitAmount - CreditAmount ) > THEN 
      SUM(DebitAmount - CreditAmount) ELSE 0 END AS DebitAmount,
    CASE WHEN SUM(DebitAmount - CreditAmount) < 0 
         THEN SUM(CreditAmount- DebitAmount) ELSE 0 END AS CreditAmount 
    FROM TblAWSLocalTrans GROUP BY ActName ORDER BY ActName"
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con); 
SqlDataAdapter da= new SqlDataAdapter();
DataTable dt= new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource = dt; 
GridView1.DataBind(); 
con.Close();
```

Comment: have you accept your previous question answer

Comment: Yes this query is working perfect for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Ans.. Use Inline Query in ado.net code.

```
    public void btn_click(object sender,EventArgs e) 
     { 
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"); 
       var command= "SELECT ActName,CASE WHEN SUM(DebitAmount - CreditAmount ) > THEN 
      SUM(DebitAmount - CreditAmount)ELSE 0 END AS DebitAmount,CASE WHEN SUM(DebitAmount - 
     CreditAmount) < 0 THEN SUM(CreditAmount- DebitAmount )ELSE 0 END AS CreditAmount 
      FROM TblAWSLocalTrans GROUP BY ActName ORDER BY ActName"
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con); 
      SqlDataAdapter da= new SqlDataAdapter();
      DataTable dt= new DataTable();
      da.Fill(dt);
      GridView1.DataSource = dt; 
      GridView1.DataBind(); 
      con.Close();
   }
```